# Performance differences C++, using windows form vs. windows console

Tags: c++, winforms, performance, console-application

Is there any differences (performance) using windows form or windows console when programming in windows visual c++.

I've heard for example that printf() in the console makes the program really slow. How is it if I want to update a label in a form? Makes that the program slow also?

Why I ask. I've been programming console applications, but now I want to create a nice GUI for my application.

If I have the classes ready (for example, directshow, opencv, and my custom classes that connect everything) is it difficult to switch to windows form application?

Thanks!

Comment: Gui programming requires a vastly different way of coding, one you'll be ill prepared for when you've only ever programmed console mode apps.  Best not to focus on perf and certainly best not to get started with DirectShow and OpenCV right away.  Get yourself a book and work through the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of output - printing something to the console via `printf` or updating a label - has some runtime cost. What you heard was probably that `printf` is more expensive than you might think, so if you call it very often you may find that it's the place where most time is spent.

Of course, the same is true for a function which updates a label or for one launching intercontinental ballistic missiles. If you do it too often, the impact becomes very noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no difference in performance because Windows console uses WinApi aswell, it's not like DOS anymore, where it was mostly independent (Win 9x). But, refreshing visual component interface takes some time too. For example when You have an application that writes 10000 lines of text, it will work much faster in console than in memo. But in many cases it is avoidable or at least You should be able to make it's speed comparable. The easiest approach in given example would be hide memo for time of adding items and display the result at the end. This will speed things up, because every time an item is added interface is being refreshed, and when hidden, not.

So, Your application, overall, will probably work a bit slower when using GUI, but coding it correctly could make the difference (almost) invisible.

Answer (score 0):

The "cost" of `printf`in console mode is largely that if you output a large amount of text to the screen, it goes scrolling. If you, for example, compare that to outputting it all to a file, it will be 10-100x faster. But if you then do `type myfile.txt` to display the file, the time it takes will be almost exactly the difference between outputting to the screen and outputting to a file.

Updating a label OR printing a small amount of text without scrolling should be about comparable, and unless you really do many hundreds per second, probably not noticeable in your total runtime.